# How does below method work in Java?

Tags: java

i am go through the below method but not getting how my seniors designed.

```
public LinkedHashMap<String,IPDFField> getFields() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, IPDFField> fields = new LinkedHashMap<String, IPDFField>();

        //^field1c^lastName^nameSuffix
        // Line One
        addField(fields,"1_1", new PDFField(27+X_OFF, 718+Y_OFF, new FieldWidthValidation(134F, "^field1_1^firstName^middleName^lastName^nameSuffix")) { //PI tab
            @Override
            public String getPrintableText(Object o) {
                Disposition d = (Disposition) o;
                return dataFormattingService.NormalizedPersonName(
                        d.getFirstName(), d.getMiddleName(), d.getLastName(), d.getNameSuffix()
                );
            }
        });
} //getFileds method ends
```

from above method they have called below addField Method but what is getPrintableText inside AddField Method

```
private void addField(HashMap<String, IPDFField> fields, String fieldKey, IPDFField field) {

        field.setFieldKey(fieldKey);
        if (field.getValidation() != null) {
            field.getValidation().setField(field);
        }

        fields.put(fieldKey, field);

    }
```

above is not full code , the main functionality is we are trying to write content into pdf but i don't want to paste my full code i just need explanation for above logic

Comment: You need to learn about anonymous classes. Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: Looks like an override of `PDFField#getPrintableText`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>       addField(/**/, new PDFField(/**/) { 
>             @Override
>             public String getPrintableText(Object o) {
>               // ...
>             }
>         });
> ```

What happens here is the creation of an *anonymous inner class*.

This anonymous inner class extends the class  `PDFField` and redefines the behavior of the method `getPrintableText`  which is defined in class  `PDFField`.

---

> sorry one more doubt addFiled we have two methods in above , one is anonymous and another is private method,may i know if they are using annonymous class then they could have declared different method name for addField which is private above? – adithyan .p

I'm not sure if I understand that comment...

The anonymous class is

```
   new PDFField(/**/) { 
        @Override
        public String getPrintableText(Object o) {
          // ...
        }
    }
```

And this is passed as a parameter to the method `addField()`.

There is no restriction on the visibility of the method that gets the anonymous class instance as a parameter.

Comment: Or perhaps `PDFField` is an interface? Seems unlikely based on the fragmentary evidence provided, but without knowing which library it's from we can't discount the possibility.

Comment: @LewBloch interfaces rarely have constructor parameters.

Comment: Oh, true. Good point. But you can't discount the possibility.

Comment: pdfField is our own class which implements our interface,anyway i got with your explanation thanks

Comment: sorry one more doubt addFiled we have two methods in above , one is anonymous and another is private method,may i know if they are using annonymous class then they could have declared different method name for addField which is private above?